# Changing ImageView size dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I have an `ImageView` sandwhiched between two `LinearLayout`. The `ImageView` has zoom capability which allows me to zoom in and out of the image - this means the image can grow up to the entire size of the screen (match_parent).

If I load a very tall (height) image, the image overlaps the two `LinearLayout` which is NOT ok when **arriving** at the screen but is ok if user has decided to zoom in later. Is there a way to "limit" the height of the ImageView on initialization but also allow it to grow the entire screen size?

The following is an example of a "tall" image being loaded incorrectly as it covers the top `LinearLayout` text:

[image]

And this is how I would like the image to be loaded, with the ability to grow to the size of the previous image:

[image]

This is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBgBlackTintDarker"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="20dp">

    <!-- Title at the top -->   
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/big_display_title_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- Title stuff here-->
    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- Middle custom ImageView with ability to zoom-->
    <com.sometimestwo.moxie.ZoomieView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/full_displayer_image_zoomie_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>  

    <!-- Bottom toolbar-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/big_display_snack_bar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        
        <!-- Bottom toolbar stuff-->  
        
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: Here's a GIF to illustrate what I am experiencing:

https://imgur.com/2Uqy4ZG

The Image zooms in and out as desired but I need the image to fit in between the title and the bottom toolbar at initialization so it does not cover anything (until the user decides to zoom).

Comment: Do You accept solution with ConstrainLayout?

Comment: Of course. I have not done much with with ConstraintLayout but I am willing to learn.

Comment: Can You share Your project?

Comment: I think it's too large to look through...But I've added an edit to my post with a GIF illustrating what I am looking for

Comment: Do you know ahead of time how large your top and bottom linearlayouts will be? Or can their size change dynamically?

Comment: The top one changes dynamically but I suppose I could make it static if it meant getting the results I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

You should sandwich the `ImageView` between two `LinearLayout`s in parent `RelativeLayout`. Change your code as below:

```
<!-- Middle custom ImageView with ability to zoom-->
<com.sometimestwo.moxie.ZoomieView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/full_displayer_image_zoomie_view"
    android:layout_below="@id/big_display_title_container"
    android:layout_above="@id/big_display_snack_bar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: This does not work because the ImageView will not be able to grow the entire size of the screen. I need to allow the image to grow up to the entire size of the screen when the user decides to zoom

Comment: So you should do a bit complicated work. You should calculate height of bottom and top LinearLayouts programmatically, then subtract it from screen height. The result is initial ImageView height. Now by calculating zoom percentage using original image height and initial height, you should set the result to ZoomieView.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a ConstraintLayout.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/big_display_title_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Title stuff here-->

</LinearLayout>


   <View
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="0dp"         
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/big_display_snack_bar_container"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/big_display_title_container"/>

   <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/big_display_snack_bar_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    </LinearLayout>    
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```